# Facebook graph api permissions on live app

Tags: facebook, xamarin, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get "user_friends" permission from Facebook. Need to screencast on the app but my app is live now. I need to take a video from my app after development. But in the documentation, it says "Test users can only be used to grant your app permissions while your app is in Development mode."
How can i develop it with a test user with all permissions?

[image]

Comment: Create a Test App version of your live app, and then use that to test & develop. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps

Comment: Thank you, im reading.